# Show Chrome Bookmarks and History in Ubuntu System search

Tags: google-chrome, search

I want Ubuntu system search and find results in my Chrome Bookmarks and History in order to quickly navigate to them. At the end I want to press `super` key, start typing the title of my chrome bookmark and after pressing enter I want Chrome to open the result.
Does anyone know if that is possible?